# ColdFusion 9.0.1 trouble adding hot fix

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, hotfix

I'm trying to add the cumulative hotfix to ColdFusion 9.0.1.  The instructions say to click on the 'i' in CFAdministrator and In the "Update File" text box, browse and select `chf9010004.jar` located under `CF901/lib/updates`.

The issue seems to be that whatever browser plugin that is being used is no longer supported by the current JRE version.  Is there a way to manually add the hotfix without this step requiring to use the Java file browser?

In Safari the Java file uploader plugin says `java out-of-date` even though I'm running the latest version.

In Chrome a message comes up that says `This site uses a plugin JAVA (TM) that will soon be unsupported`. The plugin seems to load, but never goes past saying `retreiving initial directories`

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the `Browse Server` button, just type the full path to the extracted `chf9010004.jar` file into the `Update File` text box then click the `Submit Changes` button.

The path should be something like:

```
C:\directory_where_you_extracted_the_zip\CF901\lib\updates\chf9010004.jar
```